# How to backup emails from Gmail without the attachments and images

Tags: gmail, backup, gmail-archive, gmail-attachments

I am trying to backup my Gmail because our company will be closing our business account (cost cutting) and expect us to use personal email instead. I tried Google archive, but it ends up 20GB+ even if I exclude everything (Drive, Calendar, etc) except for email. But I think all embedded images and attachments for each mail are still getting included.

Is it possible to save only the text part? (*Remove all attachments and images since I probably have them downloaded already.*)

EDIT:

I forgot to mention, our company will also sell our current domain, so my email address would not be usable anymore too, right? Can I still access the downloaded archive file without my current account?